# slick2d image java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, slick2d

this is my first time posting on here. I've been looking around for a solution but no luck so far. I'm pretty new to coding so I apologise in advance for horrible programming faux pas, anyway I'm using java and slick2d and I am coding a game.

The problem is when I run the program and try to draw an enemy, it gives me a NullPointerException, I know for a fact it's not to do with the path of the image, as I've tried it with other images that work perfectly fine. What I think is the problem is it doesn't recognise an image value but I've tried everything I can to fix it and so far no luck. I'm sure there is some very simple solution and I've had a load of trouble with this so I was just wondering if someone could give me a hand. Anyway here's the code. Thanks in advance.

```
package javagame;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.Timer;

import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.openal.Audio;
import org.newdawn.slick.openal.AudioLoader;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;


public class Play extends BasicGameState{
        int time = 0;
        int roomNo = 0;
        Image interfaceBackground, spriteImage, background, enemyImage, projectileImageLeft, projectileImageRight, projectileImageUp, projectileImageDown, health0, health1, health2, health3, health4, health5, health6, health7,  health8, health9, health10;
        Audio projectileSound;
        Sprite pChar = new Sprite(spriteImage, 400f, 400f);
        Sprite enemy = new Enemy(enemyImage, 0f, 0f);
        ArrayList<Enemy> enemyList = new  ArrayList<Enemy>();
        //Enemy skeleton = new Enemy(skeletonImage, 200, 200, 50, 50);

        public Play(int state) {
        }
        @Override
        public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg)  throws SlickException{
                projectileImageLeft = new Image("res/projectile2.png");
                projectileImageRight = new Image("res/projectile3.png");
                projectileImageUp = new Image("res/projectile1.png");
                projectileImageDown = new Image("res/projectile4.png");
                interfaceBackground = new Image("res/interfaceBackground.png");
                health0 = new Image("res/HP0.png");
                health1 = new Image("res/HP1.png");
                health2 = new Image("res/HP2.png");
                health3 = new Image("res/HP3.png");
                health4 = new Image("res/HP4.png");
                health5 = new Image("res/HP5.png");
                health6 = new Image("res/HP6.png");
                health7 = new Image("res/HP7.png");
                health8 = new Image("res/HP8.png");
                health9 = new Image("res/HP9.png");
                health10 = new Image("res/HP10.png");
                enemyImage = new Image("res/skeleton.png");
                spriteImage = new Image("res/sprite2.png");
                background = new Image("res/background.png");
                background.setFilter(Image.FILTER_NEAREST);
                spriteImage.setFilter(Image.FILTER_NEAREST);
                projectileImageLeft.setFilter(Image.FILTER_NEAREST);
                projectileImageRight.setFilter(Image.FILTER_NEAREST);
                projectileImageUp.setFilter(Image.FILTER_NEAREST);
                projectileImageDown.setFilter(Image.FILTER_NEAREST);
                interfaceBackground.setFilter(Image.FILTER_NEAREST);
                enemyImage.setFilter(Image.FILTER_NEAREST);

                }

        public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException{
                Input input= gc.getInput();
                if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_W)){pChar.MoveUp(spriteImage);}
                if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_S)){pChar.MoveDown(spriteImage);}
                if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_A)){pChar.MoveLeft(spriteImage);}
                if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_D)){pChar.MoveRight(spriteImage);}
                if(pChar.projectileCD > 200){
                if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)){pChar.shootUp(projectileImageUp);}
                else if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)){pChar.shootDown(projectileImageDown);}
                else if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)){pChar.shootLeft(projectileImageLeft);}
                else if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)){pChar.shootRight(projectileImageRight);}
                }
                pChar.update();
                enemy.update();
                enemy.generate();
                if(pChar.Health  < 1){
                        sbg.enterState(3);
                }
                time += 1;
                roomNo = pChar.roomNo;
                for(Enemy enem: enemyList){
                        enem.update();

                }

        }
        public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException{
                background.draw(0, 100, 800, 500);
                spriteImage.draw(pChar.getxPos(), pChar.getyPos(), 120f, 80f);
                pChar.draw();
                enemy.draw();
                interfaceBackground.draw(0,0,800,100);
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawString("Time:" + time/50, 50, 30);
                g.drawString("Room Number:" +roomNo, 300, 30);
                switch(pChar.Health){
                case 0:
                        health0.draw(600, 20, 150, 65);
                        break;
                case 1:
                        health1.draw(600, 20, 150, 65);
                        break;
                case 2:
                        health2.draw(600, 20, 150, 65);
                        break;
                case 3:
                        health3.draw(600, 20, 150, 65);
                        break;
                case 4:
                        health4.draw(600, 20, 150, 65);
                        break;
                case 5:
                        health5.draw(600, 20, 150, 65);
                        break;
                case 6:
                        health6.draw(600, 20, 150, 65);
                        break;
                case 7:
                        health7.draw(600, 20, 150, 65);
                        break;
                case 8:
                        health8.draw(600, 20, 150, 65);
                        break;
                case 9:
                        health9.draw(600, 20, 150, 65);
                        break;
                case 10:
                        health10.draw(600, 20, 150, 65);
                        break;
                }
                }



@Override
        public int getID(){
                return 1;
        }
}
//Sprite
package javagame;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.tests.xml.Entity;

public class Sprite{
        ArrayList<Projectile> projectileList = new  ArrayList<Projectile>();
        ArrayList<Enemy> enemyList = new  ArrayList<Enemy>();
        protected static float xPos = 400f, yPos = 400f;
    private static float Speed = 3.5f, ProjectileSpeed = 8f;
        static int AttackSpeed = 6, Health = 10;
        private int Damage = 0;
        int projectileCD = 100, roomNo = 1;
        Image SpriteImage, ProjectileImage, EnemyImage;
        Random number = new Random();

        public Sprite(Image spriteImage, float x, float y) {
                SpriteImage = spriteImage;             
        }
        public static float getSpeed(){
                return Speed;
        }
        public static float getProjectileSpeed(){
                return ProjectileSpeed;
        }
        public static int getHealth(){
                return Health;
        }
        public static int getAttack(){
                return AttackSpeed;
        }
        public int getDamage(){
                return Damage;
        }
        public float getxPos(){
                return xPos;
        }
        public float getyPos(){
                return yPos;
        }
        public void MoveLeft(Image spriteImage){
                if (xPos < 50){}
                else{xPos -= Speed;}
        }
        public void MoveRight(Image spriteImage){
                if(xPos > 670){}
                else if(((yPos > 290)&&(yPos < 380))&&(xPos>669)){
                                roomNo++;
                                xPos += 150;
                                //next room
                                }
                else{xPos += Speed;}
        }
        public void MoveUp(Image spriteImage){
                if(yPos < 150){}
                else{yPos -= Speed;}
        }
        public void MoveDown(Image spriteImage){
                if(yPos > 420){}
                else {yPos += Speed;}
        }
        public void shootUp(Image projectileImage){
                projectileList.add(new Projectile(projectileImage, xPos + 15, yPos, 0f, -8f));
                projectileCD = 0;
                Health = Health -1;
        }
        public void shootDown(Image projectileImage){
                projectileList.add(new Projectile(projectileImage, xPos + 35, yPos + 60, 0f, 8f));
                projectileCD = 0;
        }
        public void shootLeft(Image projectileImage){
                projectileList.add(new Projectile(projectileImage, xPos , yPos + 30, -8f, 0f));
                projectileCD = 0;
        }
        public void shootRight(Image projectileImage){
                projectileList.add(new Projectile(projectileImage, xPos + 60, yPos + 30, 8f, 0f));
                projectileCD = 0;
        }
        public void draw(){
                for(Projectile proj: projectileList){
                        proj.draw();   
                }
                for(Enemy enem: enemyList){
                        enem.draw();
                }
        }
                public void update(){
                        projectileCD = projectileCD + AttackSpeed;
                        for(Projectile proj: projectileList){
                                proj.move();
                                /*if(proj.xPos > 670){
                                        projectileList.remove(this);
                                }
                                else if(proj.xPos < 80){
                                        projectileList.remove(this);
                                }
                                else if(proj.yPos > 420){
                                        projectileList.remove(this);
                                        }
                                else if(proj.yPos < 80){
                                        projectileList.remove(this);
                                }*/
                        }

                }
                public void generate(){
                        switch(number.nextInt(3)){
                        case 1:
                                enemyList.add(new Enemy(SpriteImage, 100f, 100f));
                                break;
                        case 2:
                                enemyList.add(new Enemy(ProjectileImage, 100f, 100f));
                                break;
                        case 3:
                                enemyList.add(new Enemy(SpriteImage, 100f, 100f));
                                break;
                        }      
                }
        }
//Enemy
package javagame;

import java.util.Random;

import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;

public class Enemy extends Sprite{
        float xSpawn = 0, ySpawn = 0, Dx =0, Dy = 0, xPos = 0, yPos, Speed = 0;
        int AttackSpeed = 0, Health = 0, Damage;
        Image EnemyImage;
        Random number = new Random();
        public Enemy(Image enemyImage, float x, float y) {
                super(enemyImage, x, y);
                EnemyImage = enemyImage;
                AttackSpeed = number.nextInt(6);
                Damage = number.nextInt(3);
                Health = number.nextInt(4);
                Speed = number.nextInt(4);
        }
        public void draw(){
                EnemyImage.draw(xPos, yPos); <---- This is where I get the error
        }
}
```

(http://pastebin.com/PggQNWgi)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't instantiated the yPos value. You set xPos to 0 but not yPos so there's a good chance that value doesn't exist.

Comment: Changed that now, I was messing with the parameters and I guess I forgot to change it back. unfortunately still not working though.